# Android Room Multimap with left join doesn't work

Tags: android, android-room, multimap

I'm using Room's new feature of MultiMap to join 2 tables as such:

```
@Query("""
    SELECT comments.*, users.* 
    FROM comments
    LEFT JOIN users ON comments.author_id = users.id
    """)
fun getCommentsAndUsers(): Flow<Map<CommentEntity,UserEntity?>>
```

The generated code by room does not respect the declaration of UserEntity being nullable.
Am I doing something wrong or is it something currently not possible with MultiMap?

Comment: Solved!
Apparently it's important to have distinct column names in the 2 tables. After assigning unique values everything works.